# retrieve image from database but nothing shows

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form and with this form I submit image to database(I am 100% sure that this form works well and images store properly in database)
but when I try to retrieve and show them nothing happens.

```
<!-- index.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fa/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bottons/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <title> index.php </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="product-row">
        <?php include('showimages.php'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


---------showimages.php :----------------       
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'online_shopping');
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productID desc limit 8;"  ;   
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    header("Content-type: image/jpg");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {             
        echo "<div class='each-product'>
            <div class='product-image' style='background-image: url(".$row['pric1'].")'>
            </div>                 
            <i class='fa fa-heart-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            <div class='name'>".  $row['name'] ." </div>
            <div class='price'>" .$row['price'].  "<span class='toman'> dollar </span> </div>
            <div class='add-to-basket'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-lg btn-success'> <i class='fa fa-shopping-basket' aria-hidden='true'></i>  add to basket </button>
            </div>
        </div> " ;

    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing what the result of your query is?

Comment: $row['name'] and $row['price'] are working fine but $row['pric1'] shows nothing

Comment: `var_dump($row); die();` first line of the while loop and see what you get

Comment: output doesn't change .

Comment: Does your `<div class="product-image">` have a size? Did you show the source ?

Comment: yes it has ... this is the css code : .each-product .product-image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

Comment: Can you verify the output from `$row['pric1]` is returning the image link. (And also sure the its 'pric1' and not `pic1`?)

Comment: You are passing the header ContentType image/jpg, but are displaying html as well. Are you storing the raw image contents as a string in the database? If you are, you will need to create a second file, for example image.php. Then you can reference the image with background-image: url(image.php?id=$row['productID']);. Then image.php will return the header ContentType: image/jpg, query the database using the productID, and print the raw contents of the database stored image. I have done it this way in the past.

Comment: i think you are right "user9189147" ... but I am so new to php ... can you give me a code to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I do some tweak and this is true answer :

```
<div class='product-image' style='background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['pric1'])."')'>
</div>
```

(there is no need for header("Content-type: image/jpg");)